# Is it possible to schedule push notification time ? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want to schedule push notification after some time or say after 2 days 15 hours. So after 2 days 15 hours a notification will be sent to a device. 
Is it possible ? How ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a push notification originates from a server and not the phone itself you can schedule anything the provider makes available. You will have to check with your notification service provider what they make available.

However if you just need to schedule a future alert on the phone itself, you can use the UILocalNotification class. This will just kick off a notification on the device once the timer expires.